# SQL Linq syntax

Tags: .net, sql, linq

Required SQL equivalent:

```
select * from polls where (id=(select max(id) from polls where publish_at=(select max(publish_at) from polls where publish_at<='2012-08-10 00:00:00')) and status=1 )
```

I have tried this,but it gives Null whereas it should return a row.

```
var qry = db.Polls.Where(p => p.id == db.Polls.Where(x => x.publish_at == db.Polls.Max(y => y.publish_at) && x.publish_at <= System.DateTime.Today).Max(x => x.id) && p.status.Equals(PollStatus.Active)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://WhatHaveYouTried.com)

Comment: And while you have only two questions with unaccepted answers, the resulting percentage reflects poorly on you here; consider accepting at least one of the answers from your other questions.

Comment: Hey Thanks keith S for making me aware of this and Juergen Yes I have tried and updated my answer ..Offcourse with the help of the replies here!!

Comment: You should check if each subquery is returning what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be like this:

```
db.polls.Where(p => p.id == polls.Where(x => x.publish_at == polls.Max(y => y.publish_at)).Max(x => x.id));
```

Another way like this:

```
from p in db.polls
where p.id == (from x in db.polls
               where x.id == (from y in db.polls
                              where y.publish_at == db.polls.Max(y => y.publish_at)
                              select y.id).Max())
               select x.id).Max())
select p;
```

Comment: kindly see the updates in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from p in context.Polls
            where p.id == (from p2 in context.Polls
                           where p2.publish_at == context.Polls.Max(x => x.publish_at)
                           select p2).Max(y => y.id)
            select p;
```

Comment: kindly see the updates in the question

Answer (score 0):

This works beautifully:

```
var qry = db.Polls.Where(p => p.id == db.Polls.Where(x => x.publish_at == db.Polls.Where(y => y.publish_at<=System.DateTime.Today).Max(y=>y.publish_at)).Max(x => x.id) && p.status.Equals(PollStatus.Active)).FirstOrDefault();
```